# DryIOC Container Contents

Tags: dryioc

StructureMap has a super-useful debug method on the Container class called WhatDoIHave()

It shows every type in the container along with its lifecycle, guid and a bunch of other info. It's useful for debugging.

There's some info here:

http://jeremydmiller.com/2014/02/18/structuremap-3-is-gonna-tell-you-whats-wrong-and-where-it-hurts/

Does DryIOC have an equivalent debug feature?

Comment: There is a method `GetServiceRegistrations`. Is that what you're looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(I'm the creator of [DryIoc](https://bitbucket.org/dadhi/dryioc)).

You can use `container.GetServiceRegistrations()` to get registration infos as @fyodor-soikin suggested.

But at the latest version (**2.0.0-rc3build339**) I have added `VerifyResolutions` method that may help you to diagnose potential resolution problems, including missing registrations as well. Here the wiki [explaining it](https://bitbucket.org/dadhi/dryioc/wiki/ErrorDetectionAndResolution#markdown-header-verifyresolutions-is-ignorant-version-of-generateresolutionexpressions).

Example from the wiki:

```
// Given following SUT
public class RequiredDependency {}
public class MyService { public MyService(RequiredDependency d) {} }

// Let's assume we forgot to register RequiredDependency
var container = new Container();
container.Register<MyService>();

// Find what's missing
var results = container.VerifyResolutions();
Assert.AreEqual(1, results.Length);
```

Verify result is array of `ServiceRegistrationInfo` and `ContainerException` KeyValuePairs. In this example the registration info will be:

> MyNamespace.MyService registered as factory {ID=14, ImplType=MyNamespace.MyService}

And the exception will be:

> DryIoc.ContainerException: Unable to resolve MyNamespace.RequiredDependency as parameter "d"
>    in MyNamespace.MyService.
>   Where no service registrations found
>    and number of Rules.FallbackContainers: 0
>    and number of Rules.UnknownServiceResolvers: 0

**Update:**

The functionality is available in latest stable [DryIoc 2.0.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DryIoc.dll).